# Is there any legal provision in India that bans watching obscene material in private?

Tags: criminal-law, india, pornography

So far as I understand, Sections 292, 292A, 293 and 294 of the Indian Penal Code specifically criminalize **circulating** obscene material, unless such material is intended as art, education.

Is there any law in India that prevents a person from using/viewing such obscene material within privacy of the 4 walls of his/her home? Is it a crime for him/her to do it?

(For instance, watching pornography in private, though circulating it is a crime).

Answer (score 1):

Nope. With the exception of child pornography, you can view any other type of pornography legally within your home. This is mentioned in [Information Technology Bill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_Technology_Act,_2000). In fact, browsing for child porn is illegal and [can land you in jail](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/Browsing-child-porn-will-land-you-in-jail/articleshow/4134097.cms). Other than that you are free to watch porno at home legally without landing you into any trouble.